# Recursive template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates

For calculating factorial I can use :

```
template<int N> struct factorial { enum { value = N * factorial<N-1>::value }; };

template<> struct factorial<1> { enum { value = 1 }; }; //base Case
```

and then can use it like following

`x=factorial<8>::value;`

So, is it possible to get similar recursive template for

```
 unsigned Log2(unsigned n, unsigned p = 0) {
    return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
}
```

I can think of this:

```
template<int N,unsigned int P=0> struct Log2 
    { enum { value = Log2<N/2,P+1>::value }; };
```

But don't know how to set a base case.

```
 template<> struct Log2<0,???> { enum { value = ???? }; };
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use partial specialization

```
template <unsigned p>
struct Log2<0, p> { enum { value = p }; };

template <unsigned p>
struct Log2<1, p> { enum { value = p }; };
```

---

In C++11, instead of creating a template, you could turn the function to `constexpr` instead.

```
constexpr unsigned Log2(unsigned n, unsigned p = 0) {
    return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
}

std::array<int, Log2(256)> x {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
//              ^^^^^^^^^ Just a compile-time function call.
```

Comment: @P0W: Well I'm just using your implementation which returns `p` when `n <= 1`.